# Calculate the frequency for each word in text file, store it in a variable using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

but without the help of inbuilt counter function

with open(r"C:\Users\muizv\Desktop\alice_in_wonderland.txt", "rt") as f:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read the content of the file: `content = f.read()`, then use regex to find all words `words = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', content)` then loop over the list and use a dict to count the words:

```
freq = {}
for word in words:
    freq[word] = freq.get(word, 0) + 1 # adds 1 to the freq of the current word, with 0 as the default
console.log(freq)
```